# Excel VSTO ribbon DropDownItem index to -1

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a few VSTO ribbon combo boxes in a custom Exel ribbon. The two combo boxes that I am having difficulty with are CBO.Division and CBO.Category. I have the Division_ItemsLoading method doing a database query and filling the division combo box with the results.

The CBO_Division_TextChanged has a query that returns all category items and uses the selected text in the division combo box as parts of its query

Not all Divisions have a category and I need to know how to clear out the currently selected items from the category combo box when selecting a new division. How is this accomplished?

Here is my code thus far:

```
 #region ComboBox: Division 
    private void cbo_Division_ItemsLoading(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) //cbo_Division
    {
        cbo_Division.Items.Clear();

        try
        {
            using (con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(groupname, CHARINDEX('_', Groupname) + 1,
                                              CHARINDEX('/', groupname) - 1 - CHARINDEX('_', Groupname))
                                              FROM groups where Groupname like @division;", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@division", "Approvers.CCB%");
                    using (rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            var rddi = this.Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                            rddi.Label = rdr[0].ToString();
                            cbo_Division.Items.Add(rddi);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            rdr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void cbo_Division_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        cbo_Category.Items.Clear();

        try
        {
            //Clear all approvers
            XLS_RemoveStakeHolders.RemoveApprovers();

            using (con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select RIGHT(groupname, len(groupname) - charindex('/',Groupname))  
                                              FROM groups where Groupname like @division ORDER BY groupName;", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@division", "Approvers.CCB_" + cbo_Division.Text + "%");
                    using (rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            var rddi = this.Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                            rddi.Label = rdr[0].ToString();
                            cbo_Category.Items.Add(rddi);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            XLS_RangeData division = new XLS_RangeData(cbo_Division.Text);
            division.SetDivision();

            XLS_RangeData category = new XLS_RangeData(cbo_Category.Text);
            category.SetCategory();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            rdr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to invalidate the category combo box on the change event of the division combo box. This method will trigger a reload of the source of the category combox box.

```
    public void OnChange(Office.IRibbonControl control, string text)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (control.Id)
            {
                case "cbo_Division":
                    ribbon.InvalidateControl("cbo_Category");
                    break;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Unexpected Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of the XML for the on change event.

```
                <comboBox
                        id="cbo_Division"
                        label="Division: "
                        onChange="OnChange"
                        getText="GetLabelText"
                        getItemCount="GetItemCount"
                        getItemLabel="GetItemLabel"
                        sizeString= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                        screentip="Division Name"
                        supertip="This is the Division name."
                        />
```